# SwiftUI Run recurring background task

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im trying to implement a system that's schedules a background task to fetch some API data and then sends the user a notification ones that's completed

Unfortunatly, the background tasks doesn't seem to work as it should be.
The notification does pop up sometimes, but not always.

I have the following code right now

When the user pressed a button a new background task will be scheduled

```
let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "randomImage")
request.earliestBeginDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 60, to: Date())
do {
    try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    print("Background Task Scheduled!")
} catch(let error) {
    print("Scheduling Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Then in the main app file the following code is added

```
struct TrainSoundTrackerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("randomImage")) {
            await refreshAppData()
        }
    }
    func refreshAppData() async {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Train information available"
        content.subtitle = "Check it now!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("IronBell.aif"))
        
        try? await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test", content: content, trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)))
    }
}
```

I have added the permission to the info.plist file.

I want to achieve that every 15 minutes for example the background tasks will be executed and the user received a push notification to their device

Comment: They are not guaranteed, this is expected behavior. You can send remote push notification with some service such as firebase or a custom server.

Comment: What do you mean with expected behavior?

Comment: They won’t run every 15 minutes background tasks are not guaranteed to run at all or even at a certain time. The 15 minute interval is a request but it may or may not be granted on time or at all.

Comment: Alright, is there a other solution to schedule tasks to execute after a specific amount of time?

Comment: Like I said in the first comment, remote notifications

Comment: I think you are confusing a more limited SwiftUI's background tasks (which are for UI data refreshing and so on) with a more general BackgroundTasks framework (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks), which allows to accomplish many other things. Remember that UI is not guaranteed to live when the app is in the background. So you need to detach your background work from UI.

Comment: @rapiddevice they are the same thing, the SwiftUI part in the code is the same as registering with the code you are referencing. The window group it is attached to is the very top of a SwiftUI lifecycle app.

Comment: @loremipsum it's a good thing to know. Do we have an Apple-confirmed source for this information, or is it more an accidental discovery by someone?

Comment: @rapiddevice I got it from the WWDC video that talked about it a few months ago. Ill see if I can find the exact one.